# Meteor.js: iron:router including name

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes

In tutorials I found two ways of using iron:router:

First one:

```
Router.route("/", function(){
    this.render("navbarMain", {
        to: "navigation"
    });
    this.render("firstPage",{
        to: "main"
    });
```

Second one:

```
Router.route("/", {
    name: "home",
    template: "home"
});
```

I would like to add name attribute to the first code; I tried adding it in differenet places, but none seems to work. Where should I put it or there is no way to combine those two? In that case, how can I refer to the root page (in pathFor)?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use the first code in that format? Is there a reason you can't define `navbarMain` and `firstPage` distinctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
Router.route("/", function(){
  this.render("navbarMain", {
    to: "navigation"
  });
  this.render("firstPage",{
    to: "main"
  });
}, {
  name: 'home'
});
```